# Spring boot + Rabbit MQ Process messages paralally

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have observed that I have multiple messages in queue but my worker is picking messages one by one, it's not processing messages parallally. What I am doing wrong here ? How can i process multiple messages parallally to utilizing my worker processing at most. Any best practice ?

I am not sure what concurrency value 8 doing here.

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: 
    port: 
    username: 
    virtual-host: 
    password: 
    listener:
      simple:
        concurrency: 8
        prefetch: 8
```

**Bean config:**

```
 @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("testQ", true);
    }

    @Bean
    TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange("testE");
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind("testQ").to("testE").with("a.b.c");
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                             MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames("testQ");
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Receiver receiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "handleMessage");
    }
```

Comment: Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Answer (score 0):

I think if you create SimpleMessageListenerContainer in your code yourself, then you could specify the parameter "concurrency" right in your code. For example:

```
@Bean
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                         MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames("testQ");

    container.setConcurrency("8"); //set 'Concurrency' property for your container

    container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
    return container;
}
```